# How to display Next and Previous item in October CMS

Tags: octobercms

I made a custom and simple blog module.

I'm trying to display, on the single article page, the next article and the previous one.

Then I tried, with help I got here, in the model

```
    public function onRun (){

     $this->articles = $this->getNextArticleAttribute();

     $this->articles = $this->getPreviousArticleAttribute();


   }

    public function getNextArticleAttribute() {

    return self::where('id','<', $this->id)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();

}

    public function getPreviousArticleAttribute() {

    return self::where('id','>', $this->id)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();
```

And in the single page

```
            {% set previous = __SELF__.previousArticle() %}

            <div class="wrapper-small">
              <div id="single-pagination" class="blog-pagination fixed">
                <ul class="pagination clearfix">
                  <li class="prev"><a href="/news/{{previous.slug}}" class="pseudo-ajax">
                    <span class="text">Précédent</span>
                    <span class="page-image"><span><img src="{{previous.newsimage.path}}" alt="SEO Name" /></span></span>
                  </a>

              {% set next = __SELF__.nextArticle() %}

                  </li>
                  <li class="next "><a href="/news/{{next.slug}}" class="pseudo-ajax">
                    <span class="text">Suivant</span>
                    <span class="page-image"><span><img src="{{next.newsimage.path}}" alt="SEO Name" /></span></span>
                  </a></li>
                </ul>
              </div> <!-- END .single-pagination -->
            </div> <!-- END .wrapper-small -->
```

So I really don't know what I'm missing...

Comment: can you please share what is not working and what output you get for the current script so we can help you

Comment: Hello @HardikSatasiya, thanks for your answer. Actually this code doesn't output anything (no slug in {{previous.slug}} and no image in {{next.newsimage.path}}). I don't know how to make a dd to see if I get anything else...

Answer (score 1):

First you have to declare previousArticle and nextArticle as [accessors](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/mutators#accessors-and-mutators) in the model:

`public function getNextArticleAttribute() {`
and
`public function getPreviousArticleAttribute() {`

And then, from your model instance, you can get the next or previous article so:

```
$model = Article::find($id); // instantiate an article model
$model->nextArticle; // return a model article
$model->previousArticle; // both without parentesis
```

---

On the other hand, I think that you don't need to call `$post = Article::where('slug',$slug)->first();` in both functions because `$this` is actually the current article, so, nextArticle may look like this:

```
public function getNextArticleAttribute() {
    return self::where('id','>', $this->id)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately I'm still stuck and sure I'm missing something.

Comment: @DVst I see your modifications and I think I confused you by giving you two alternatives. I will modify my answer to give you the best alternative from my point of view.